# Using multiple FITS file

Tags: python, astropy

How can I open two fits file at the same time with astropy? Is it possible to work on multiple FITS file at the same time or do I have to work on one at a time?

Comment: This sounds like something I'm proficient at/have probably done before, but given your question as it stands, I have no idea what you're actually asking.

Comment: You realize that you've used virtually no punctuation in the entire question? That makes it even harder to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can open as many FITS files as you like. Each is represented by a HDUList object.

```
from astropy.io import fits
hdu_list1 = fits.open('file1.fits')
hdu_list2 = fits.open('file2.fits')
```

Then I'd suggest to call this to see what the FITS files contain:

```
hdu_list1.info()
hdu_list2.info()
```

You can then access any header and data information in those FITS files and do what you want. It goes something like this:

```
array1 = hdu_list1[0].data
array2 = hdu_list2[0].data
ratio = array1 / array2
```

If you want to make a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(ratio)
```

The Astropy docs are very good. E.g. you could start to learn about `astropy.io.fits` [here](https://astropy-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rst-tutorials/FITS-images.html) or [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html).